# How to build a new column in Pandas from a Conditional (New Column should output strings)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a column in pandas using a conditional to create a qualitative observation.

For example, if the data frame looks like this:

```
      Distance      
1     1              
2     5                        
3     40              
4     15
```

I want to create a new column (let's call it `df['length']`) which is an observation on the distances.

For example:

```
if df[Distance] = 1:
  print('Short')
```

I want 'Short' to be input into the new column for each row that fits the conditional.

Or for example:

```
if df[Distance] > 10:
  print('Long')
```

I want each row that fits the conditional in the new column to be 'Long'.

How would I go about doing this?

I'm trying to write it into a function. This is what I have now:

```
def trip_distance(row):    

    df = pd.read_csv('taxi_january_standard_rate.csv')

    if df['trip_distance'] > 50 :
        return "Long"
```

and then I try and use that to populate a new column:

```
df['trip_length'] = df.apply(trip_distance , axis=1)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. It's giving me an error:

> ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')

Basically, I'm trying to give 5 Qualitative descriptions to a column in a taxicab data set, where for each distance greater than a certain value, I describe it as 'Long' or if it is close to the mean, I describe it as 'Average', etc.

Comment: [Compute column based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161537/compute-columns-based-on-multiple-conditions/50161619#50161619) may be of use. You basically want to create 2 lists, one of the conditions and one of the values assigned if that condition is True and then use `numpy.select` to assign the values to a new column

Comment: To give an example to @ALollz's strategy: `df['length'] = np.select([df.Distance < 2, df.Distance > 10], ['short', 'long'], 'average')`. You can read more about `np.select` on the relevant [documentation pages](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Answer (score 6):

you need [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
 import numpy as np
 df['Length']=np.where(df['Distance']>10,'Long','Short')
```

if you want multiple conditions, go with  @sacul  solution, use [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
df['length'] = np.select([df.Distance < 2, df.Distance > 10], ['short', 'long'], 'average')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['Distannce'])
>>> df
   Distannce
0          1
1          5
2         40
3         15

>>> df['length'] = np.nan
>>> df['length'][df['Distannce'] > 10] = 'Long'
>>> df
   Distannce length
0          1    NaN
1          5    NaN
2         40   Long
3         15   Long
>>> df['length'][df['Distannce'] == 1] = 'Short'
>>> df
   Distannce length
0          1  Short
1          5    NaN
2         40   Long
3         15   Long
>>>
```

Let me know if it helps, also please mark as answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could do:

```
df.loc[df['Distance'] > 10, 'length'] = 'Long'
df.loc[df['Distance'] == 1, 'length'] = 'Short'
```

**Output:**

```
   Distance length
0   1      Short
1   5      NaN
2   40     Long
3   15     Long
```

You can fill NaN with whatever value you want using fillna