# Categorise column based upon another column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a DataFrame as follows:
col1 num agg_col
12  200   0
13  300   0
14  400   0
15  500   0
16  600   0
17  700   0

I am trying to populate agg_col based upon the values in col1.
For instance, if col1 is 12 - 14, the populate 1 on agg_col, 15-16, 
populate 2 on agg_col. if col1 = 17, populate 3.

I wrote the following python code:

```
df['agg_col'][(df['col1'] >= 12) & (df['col1'] <= 14)] = 1
```

But I am stuck here and am not being able to proceed. Please help!!!

Comment: Trying to find a more popular duplicate, but basically you want to use `np.select` to define a list of the conditions and another one for the choices. or `pd.cut` if it's a continuous set of bins. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161537/compute-columns-based-on-multiple-conditions/50161619#50161619)

Comment: @ALollz... perfect thanks!!!

Comment: What was the error that you obtained? This statement seems to work perfectly for me when I tried it out.

Comment: @thegreatcoder......SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead. This was the warning!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try look at `pd.cut`

```
pd.cut(df.col1,[0,15,16,17],labels=[1,2,3])
Out[988]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    3
Name: col1, dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1 < 2 < 3]
```